# An integer sequence problem Generalization

Tags: number-theory

> Suppose $x_0=2,\; |x_n| = |x_{n-1}+1|. $ Find the smallest possible
>   value of $|x_1+\cdots+x_{2019}|$.

Here is the trick that solves the problem quite easily:

$|x_{k+1}| = |x_k + 1|\iff x_{k+1}^2 - x_k^2 -1 = 2 x_k\implies$
$x_1+\cdots+x_n =\frac{x_{n+1}^2 - x_1^2 - n}{2} = \frac{x_{n+1}^2 -(n+9)}{2}$
Now we need only to select $x_{n+1}$ from its possible values to
make the absolute value of the quotient minimal

**How to generalize?**

What I tried: Find $|s|_{\min}(n): =\min_{x\in\mathcal{A}}\big|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\big|$
where $\mathcal{A}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}: x_0=2,\,|x_{k+1}|=|x_k+1|\;(k\in\mathbb{N})\}$.

Let $\Omega=\{(s,v): s=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k,\;v = x_n,\, x\in\mathcal{A},\;n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and

define $f:\mathcal{P}(\Omega)\to\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ as $\{(s,v)\}\mapsto\{(s+w(v+1),w(v+1)) \mid w=\pm 1\}$
with $f(S) = \bigcup_{v\in S} f(\{v\})$. Then clearly $\Omega = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} f^n(\{(0,2)\}).$

Thus $|s|_{\min}(n) = \min\{|s|:\,(s,v)\in f^n(\{(0,2)\})$.